# How can I can change background colour in java when user clicks on a spot on my application window?

Tags: java, swing

Currently I have made text labels and placed them on my window, instructed them to perform action upon mouseClick, but this has increased my coding as I have several locations the user can change colour from. Below, is one of the label codes I came up up;

```
    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("");
    label_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }
    });
    label_1.setEnabled(false);
    label_1.setBounds(0, 0, 19, 19);
    contentPane.add(label_1);
```

but this is adding unnecessary code to my program, what I want is when the user clicks on a portion of the window say middle (about 1 cm spot) give or take few mm the background colour changes.

I think it can be done by adding a listener for mouseClicked on the content pane itself and then telling the code once a spot is clicked change colour to contentPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN); I have 2 spots I want to change colour from.

I cannot figure out out to tell my code so that if a specific area is clicked it changes the background colour of the window.

Thanks.

-----Edit-----

I am using a contentPane at the moment to add elements on my window, my code for that currently looks like this

---

```
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 584, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
```

### contentPane.setLayout(null);

Can't I just add a mouse listenter event to getBound location of user click using this, for example

add this piece of code to my previous one code that adds contentPane

```
        contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
```

and in the public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  } add if statements i.e. if (getBound(0,0,20,20)) contentPane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

Something along the lines of this, this isn't working.

Comment: Is the `x` and `y` position of the click enough for you to know if it's on the spot you want?

Comment: A runnable example will do much better

Comment: That should do the trick, btw, I edited my code a bit so it is more clear of what I need, I think getting the x and y location of mouseclick would be ideal, but how can I implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the query in the right sense, you expect to set background colour on the `Content Pane` by simply clicking on some specified location of the said `Content Pane`. If that be the case, please have a look at this example code, and try to click on the `TOP RIGHT CORNER`, `LEFT BOTTOM CORNER` or `CENTER` of the `Content Pane` to see the colour change. It simply creates three `Rectangle` objects specifying each area on the `Content Pane` where one can click to change the background colour. Simply by checking if the **X, Y Co-ordinate** is contained in any of the **Rectangle Bounds** by calling `rectangle.contains(int x, int y)` method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LocationExample {

    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tField;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    private static final int RECTANGLE_DIMENSION = 50;

    private List<Rectangle> rectangles;
    private Random random;

    private MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
                if (rectangle.contains(x, y)) {
                    contentPane.setBackground(getRandomColor());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private ComponentAdapter componentAdapter = new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
            setRectangleBounds();
        }
    };

    public LocationExample() {
        random = new Random();
        rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    }   

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Location Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return (new Dimension(300, 300));
            }
        };
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        contentPane.addComponentListener(componentAdapter);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        setRectangleBounds();
    }

    private void setRectangleBounds() {
        getRectangle(contentPane.getWidth() - RECTANGLE_DIMENSION, 0);
        getRectangle(0, contentPane.getHeight() - RECTANGLE_DIMENSION);
        getRectangle((contentPane.getWidth() / 2) - (RECTANGLE_DIMENSION / 2),
                    (contentPane.getHeight() / 2) - (RECTANGLE_DIMENSION / 2));
    }

    private void getRectangle(int x, int y) {
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(x, y, RECTANGLE_DIMENSION, RECTANGLE_DIMENSION));
    }

    private Color getRandomColor() {
        return (new Color(random.nextInt(256),
            random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LocationExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! that is what I need (the concept of changing colour in a window by clicking set location), I will try and understand the code and adapt it to my needs and will let you know what I get at the end. Thanks for the help. I was looking for a smaller code to be honest though but this does the job. if you don't mind me asking, can this not be done in less lines.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, you can create a `List` of `Rectangle`s and simply iterate over that list and check if `Rectangle.contains(x, y)` is __true or false__, that part can be reduced to a single liner :-) Though will think on this too, if any thingy comes up, on which I can reduce the code size :-) For the REST, you are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) Do remember, in this example, the call to `setRectangleBounds()` is important, since it will only work after the call to the `pack() of JFrame`, since only after this call, components realize their size truly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding one Listener for the whole screen will probably not work since every object on the screen will catch and consume the Event when it is clicked and not pass it on to a higher level. So if you have a Panel with a Label on it and you click onto the Label it will catch the MouseEvent and not pass it on to the Panel.

But you might be able to get around that by doing something like that:

Make a MouseListener that gets your bottom-level-panel/pane passed on creation. In mouseClicked do something like that:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    bottomLevelPane.mouseClicked(e);
}
```

Now implement this mouseClicked-method in your bottomLevelPane to do whatever you want it to do when it gets clicked.

Then create one instance of your MouseListener and add it to every Element on the screen.
Now you only need one method to actually handle the changing-color-part and one line for each Element on the screen.

Comment: I revised my code a bit, to illustrate myself better, I am hoping to get something like that, basically, I have 4 labels at the moment, in 4 different location that when clicked change the background colour, but I find that quite repetitive as it is using unnecessary code to add label, size it, position it etc. and then tell it to change colour, but I don't see the point of adding those labels if in java code I am able to getBound of the user click as that will allow me to add if, else if statements to change background colour.

Comment: @user3253675 _"but I find that quite repetitive as it is using unnecessary code to add label, size it, position it etc"_ That's what methods are for. Create a method the returns a label, and takes arguments for location and color. Then just instantiate your labels with the method.

Comment: Wouldn't that still mean I have to create 4 individual labels, set its bounds etc. separately.